# Why is parseInt displaying Nan? - Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, parseint

I am currently iterating through an array and adding the key to my panels array. I am getting the correct length of the array which is three but my parseint is displaying NaN. How can I convert the key which is a string to an int to display panel-0 for example instead of panel-NaN.

````
Object.keys(this.Category).forEach((key) => {
      this.panels.push(parseInt(key, 3));
      this.activeIds = this.panels.map(p => 'panel-' + p);
    });```
````

Comment: Please add the code with `this.category` object properties.

Comment: Your "key" is a number? BTW has no sense in the same loop map this.activeIds (you should make it outside the forEach). BTW2, really I don't know why is the reason you need the "activeIds". I'm prety sure you can use some kind of ViewChildren to get the elements

Comment: this.category contains 3 strings namely "Car", "motorbike" and "Truck". Hence I want to add to my panels array for each index of category. so panel-0 , panel-1 and panel-2.

Comment: No my key is not a number and yes thank you for the activeIDs I am aware but seeing as it only happens once it wont increment. All im trying to do is convert the key string to an integer as I have previously explained.

Comment: `this.activeIds=Object.keys(this.Category).map((key,index) => 'panel-'+index)`. Remember, map, forEach, find... admit as second argument the "index"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are doing is `parseInt('Car' 3)`, since "Car" is not a number you will get `NaN`

probaby you want something like this:

```js
Object.keys(this.Category).forEach((key) => {
   this.panels.push('panel-' + panels.length + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Parseint takes a string and a number between 2,36 (including both ends) called a radix. It eliminates all whitespace and then starts asking "is this number between 0-(radix-1)"? If the first character it finds, after it's out of whitespace, isn't what it considers to be a number, that's one of two conditions when it will spit out a NaN. It then evaluates character by character till it finds a number. `parseInt("-bob",36)` will give an integer equal to -bob base 36 (aka -15131). `parseint("3",3)` will give you NaN. `parseint("  1234567890", 10)` gives 1234567890.

Your example is drawing off a key. Without knowing *what* the key is *it might start with invalid characters*. But, assuming you've done your due diligence and cleaned up the data. You're also asking the data to be a number base 3. The initial character can sometimes determine the base when you rely on a default radix. If you firmly want numbers between 0-9 (everyday base ten numbers) you ought to put in 10 as the second argument. If you don't put the radix in yourself, it might decide a number starting with 0 is in base 8 or 16 depending on the operating environment.

[Mozilla's documentation describes the behavior in detail as well as edge cases and work arounds.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)